# Git repos setup for multiple dependent projects

Tags: git

I'm  looking for an advice how to manage source code between couple of projects where a subset of files (directory) should be shared between both. 
Currently we have a single project A under one git repo. We are planing to port the app to anither runtime - project B. This would involve simply sharing `www` directory between both frameworks. So in abstract view the layout is as follows:

```
-----------             ------------
|    A    |             |    B     |
|---------|             |----------|
|   www   | <- shared-> |   www    |
-----------             ------------
```

Development primarily happens on `A` repo. We need ability to somehow to be able to merge any changes mage in `www A` to `www B`
It seems like we need 3 repos `A`, `B` and `www` where `www` would be nested within the other two. However I'm not sure whether nesting repositories is a best way to approach this. The other possibility there seems to exist is git submoduled but on the lack of personal experience I'm not sure if its a right solution for our setup.

Any ideas/suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to investigate `submodules` and put `www` in a third directory - but be aware that submodules have their own complications.

Comment: In the simplest case you can just two branches in *one* repository.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to achieve this.

Setting up `www` as the submodule, located in a separate directory, then you can keep the subfolder `www` inside `A` and `B` is synced with the power of Git Submodules.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to block commit from A and B into www? I mean if there is development to be done on www it must be done separately. Not from A and B.